# Laravel Routes with Vue Router (SPA) Not Working as normal

Tags: laravel, vue-router

I am trying to create a Laravel Vue SPA application. And it seems that I cannot get the route all to function properly. Everytime I use the get('{any}') all my axios get methods call returns the index.blade.php. But if I define all routes in routes.js with more or less the same signature in my web.php (Laravel) my axios routes in getting the data works fine.

web.php

```
// This work but every time I do an Axios call it returns my index.blade.php
Route::get('{any}', 'SiteController')->where('any', '.*');

// This works if I define all routes, with axios fetching data normally and 
// displaying the data in Vue normally
Route::get('/', 'SiteController');
Route::get('/blog', 'SiteController');
Route::get('/post/{postId?}', 'SiteController');
```

routes.js

```
const routes = [
    { path: '*', component: Home },
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Home,
        children: [
            {
                name: 'blog',
                path: '/blog',
                component: PageBlogLists,
            },
            {
                name: 'post',
                path: '/post/:page_id',
                component: PageBlog,
            },
        ],
    },
];

 export default new VueRouter({
        base: '/',
        fallback: true,
        mode: 'history',
        routes: routes,
    });
```

Comment: Moving `any` route to be the last route in your web.php should fix your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I finally got it working I've changed my routes to

```
 Route::get('/{any}', 'SiteController')->where('any', '^(?!api).*$');
```

and move all my API requests to the api.php file

```
Route::resource('/posts', 'WordpressController');
```

router.js and axios works fine now :)

Answer (score 2):

So first the root view, I do not know how does yours look like but it should be something like this

```php
Route::get('{path}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('path', '(.*)');
```

Second, you are building SPA, you should not be using `web.php`, you should use `api.php`

if you have to and really want to use `web.php`, you can move the `any` down to the bottom, and prefix all the other routes with something else.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a clear picture of the other codes you have in your hands.

But for laravel vue router, this reference helps me a lot

> https://medium.com/@weehong/laravel-5-7-vue-vue-router-spa-5e07fd591981

You could give it a try. Hope this helps.

Comment: Already done with that. My problem is with the axios returning the whole view blade instead of the JSON object